# Plotting a piece wise function using matplotlib results in ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a piece wise function using `matplotlib`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pwf(x):
    return 0 if x < 0 else 1
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
plt.plot(x, pwf(x))
```

and I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

However, on using `(x < 0).any()` I simply get `True` and on `(x < 0).all()` I get `False`, neither of which is suitable for my case.

I found the answer here: [Python Error: Using matplotlib: Truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565006/python-error-using-matplotlib-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-eleme), but the question and answer are so bloated with unnecessary code that I decided to post a concise solution out of it.

Comment: Add a `print(x)` to `pwf`.  And a `print(x<0)`.  If `x` has more than one element, that won't work in a `if/else` clause.

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
def pwf(x):
    return (x < 0).astype(float)
```

or, for a solution that would work with numbers other than 0 and 1,

```
def pwf(x):
    return np.array([1,0])[(x < 0).astype(int)]
```

The general solution to such kind of problem would be to vectorize the function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def pwf(x):
    return 0 if x < 0 else 1

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

plt.plot(x, np.vectorize(pwf)(x))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use Python's list comprehension:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = [pwf(x) for x in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Credit goes to **@Mike Müller** for his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34565170/7769052.